# How can I check if a value e.g. name exists in a collection within any of documents in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-database

I want to check if a value e.g. (name: ‘John’) exists in the collection of any document in my Cloud Firestore, because if it does I do not want to create a new document with that name (in this case ‘John’). How can I check if the name exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have in Firestore a collection called "users", to check if a user with the name of "John" already exists, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("users");
Query queryUsersByName = usersRef.whereEqualTo("name", "John");
queryUsersByName.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "name already exists");
                } else {
                    //Do what you need to do
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The result of the above code will be a log statement with the message "name already exists", if a user with the name of "John" already exists in the "users" collection.

Comment: in addition to @Alex answer, to know if the name doesnt exist, add an if statement before the iteration to check if the task.getResult().isEmpty(), if its empty that means there is no user with that name.